# Teradata вывести даты понедельника и воскресенья по дате

Tags: sql, teradata

Пытаюсь сделать следующее.
есть таблица которая содержит дату и два поля со значениями.

```
model_date  c   b

22.08.2020  7   22
08.12.2020  3   8
19.08.2020  4   21
01.08.2020  7   1
02.02.2020  1   2
18.07.2020  7   18
```

Допустим 22.08.2020 , нужно определить какой это день недели (это суббота), и вычеслить дату первого дня недели. То есть для этой даты начало недели (понедельник) будет 17.08.2020 а последний день недели 23.08.2020. И после чего сгрупировать данные в столбцах "с" и "b" которые входят в эту неделю (с 17-23.08.2020).

и по итогу должна быть такая таблица

```
start_date   end_date    model_date  c   b

17.08.2020   23.08.2020  22.08.2020  7   43
...
и так далее для каждой даты.
```

Подскажите как можно это сделать ? через sys_calendar не получается

**UPD!** При указание следующей строки кода, это не срабатывает для всех значений model_date.

```
(td_day_of_week(date) + 5) MOD 7
```

Как сделать так, что бы при различной дате, находить даты понедельника и воскресенья в которые входит эта дата ?

Comment: https://docs.teradata.com/r/1DcoER_KpnGTfgPinRAFUw/WwmkInjByOtZwozY4G2UwA функция td_day_of_week(). Правда, с точки зрения Teradata неделя начинается с воскресенья. Так что если от даты отнять её `(td_day_of_week(date) + 5) MOD 7` - получишь понедельник текущей недели. Ещё плюс 6 дней - получишь воскресенье.

Comment: Да только как мне определить этот недельный интервал. что бы потом можно было использовать условие where model_date between start_date and end_date ?

Comment: Ну я ж вроде всё необходимое дал. Чего ещё нехватает?

Comment: Этот код выводит значение типа int (целое число). В задаче указано, что есть определённая дата. и по ней нужно найти начало и конец недели (то есть понедельник и воскресенье) в формате date

Comment: *Так что если **от даты отнять** её `(td_day_of_week(date) + 5) MOD 7` - получишь понедельник текущей недели.*

Comment: Значени которое возвращает запрос select (td_day_of_week(date) + 5) MOD 7 будет целое число а не дата. И когда от даты в фотмате 'yyyy-mm-dd' отнимается данное значение, получается просто дата - 1 день .

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124659/discussion-between-wilteratenau-and-akina).